# Where can I store the iOS device token for later use?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

Right now I'm getting the device token via `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. However, I need to use the device token later on in my application after my user logs in.

How can I access the deviceToken from elsewhere in application later on, and if I cannot, how/where can I store it in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` so I can retrieve it later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way is to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Saving:

```
NSUserDefaults * ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setObject:myPushToken forKey:@"currentPushToken"];
[ud synchronize];
```

Restoring:

```
NSString * currentPushToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentPushToken"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use `keychain` for such data.

Add this class funcs to your project

```
import UIKit
import Security
class Keychain {

  class func save(key: String, data: NSData) -> Bool {
    let query = [
        kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
        kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
        kSecValueData as String   : data ]

    SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionaryRef)

    let status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionaryRef, nil)

    return status == noErr
  }

  class func load(key: String) -> NSData? {
    let query = [
        kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
        kSecReturnData as String  : kCFBooleanTrue,
        kSecMatchLimit as String  : kSecMatchLimitOne ]

    var dataTypeRef :Unmanaged<AnyObject>?

    let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &dataTypeRef)

    if status == noErr {
        return (dataTypeRef!.takeRetainedValue() as NSData)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
  }

  class func delete(key: String) -> Bool {
    let query = [
        kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrAccount as String : key ]

    let status: OSStatus = SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionaryRef)
    return status == noErr
  }

  class func clear() -> Bool {
    let query = [ kSecClass as String : kSecClassGenericPassword ]
    let status: OSStatus = SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionaryRef)   
    return status == noErr
  }
}
```

And you use it like this

**To store (pass is the string in your case , the token)**

```
if let data = pass.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,allowLossyConversion: false)  {
  let saveSuccess = Keychain.save("Password", data: data)
}
```

**To load**

```
data = Keychain.load("Password") 
var pass =NSString(data: data, encoding: UInt())
```